# Reducing hard surface topology

Tags: topology

I have a blend file with really nice hard surface topology.

However, it's too detailleds. It's like a subdivision modifier was applied. I'm not sure if that is true.

[image]

I'm looking for an automatic way to reduce the dense topology while still keeping the "architecture" of the original topology (which I think is pretty good) intact. By "architecture" I mean that the geometry was started using primitives and not something like a 3D scan.

The goal is a low poly game model of around 2.000 triangles.

Here is what I imagine an automatic tool should do.
I would like to remove like every 3 of 4 vertices.

[image]

How could this be done?

Here is the [blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51730).

Edit: I have tried to apply the suggestion of Checker Deselect, but I think the geometry doesn't allow applying it the way it was suggested to me:

[image]

How could I select the "correct" geometry to apply the Checker Deselect?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "reduce the dense topology while still keeping the original topology" it's not possible to have both, you either decimate or make retopo of highpoly and e.g. bake maps from highpoly to lowpoly or use highpoly. What is the final use of the model?

Comment: @MrZak Thank you. I have edited my post to indicate the purpose and what I mean by "original topology".

Answer (score 3):

[image: Checker Deselect]

You could use *Checker Deselect* and *Dissolve Edges* to get rid of this kind of pattern.

- Select an *Edge Ring*. (Click Edge with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>)
- Choose *Select* > *Checker Deselect*
- Set Parameters to *Nth Selection* = 2, *Skip* = 2, *Offset* = 0
- Hit <kbd>X</kbd> for the *Delete Menu* and choose *Dissolve Edges*

Comment: Unfortunately the geometry isn't this simple, and it doesn't work. Instead of dissolving each 2nd edge, it remove the vertices completely for me.

Comment: You can go in parts with the Checker Deselect by hiding parts of the mesh, like the iron sides, before dissolving. Depending on the model, doing the Dissolve manually or using the above-mentioned Un-Subdivide might be the more economical option.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will experiment now.

Comment: I have edited my post. I've tried your suggestion, but I don't think my geometry is "ready" for it.

Comment: I have seen a great suggestion in another question: Select a model part by using Ctrl + L, then Ctrl + E and then Un-Subdivide. Works pretty nicely!!

Comment: Do you perhaps see where the triangles are in that model? I don't see like 30 k triangles in this model. More like 5 k. At first I thought there was a subdivision modifer attached, but there isn't any. I just don't see where this massive amount of triangles are in that blend that. Thank you!

Comment: I think you just need to apply the modifier for it to take effect.

Comment: I meant to say that (without any modifier applied), the .blend file reports many more triangles than are actually present in the scene. This once happened to me, and after some investigation, I noticed that there's a subdivision modifier present which raised the triangle report, even when not applied. Once I removed this modifier, the triangle report was fine again. However, in this .blend file I don't have any modifier applied, and I wonder why Blender reports so many triangles. I just don't see them in the scene.

Comment: That is actually a different question, just open a new one, if you like. When last I had a look at the file I did not notice anything amiss with it. A few loose edges on the grenade, but all the barrels have a resolution of 32, so that just adds up.

Answer (score 3):

For shapes like primitives and quad topology [Decimate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) modifier set to *Unsubdivide* with even number of iterations could work.

[image]

Note though that this is very simple solution which has a lot of downsides.
In particular, it will behave badly on any surface similar to one filled with *Grid Fill* (note that there is triangle fan on the gif and it's for reason).
Also to mention is that *Unsubdivide* method doesn't have limit by vertex groups which means it will try to decimate everything in the given object and it won't perform quite well with uneven or more organic surfaces (you could of course split by objects which isn't always possible).
So this solution with modifier is generally quite task specific and might not work good as well in another scenario.